# how to obtain google map directions api key?

Tags: php, mysql

we need to put api key in our code in order to show directions to the destination of the people before, google used to give api key once we sign up now, it is not happening like that can some one please let me know how to get the api key

Answer (score 0):

This is where you can get a key:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

First you need to login with your gmail account and then go to

```
http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html
```